# import formulas as values using readxl::read_excel

Tags: r, excel, date, formula, readxl

I have a .xlsx spreadsheet with 2 sheets.

This is a screenshot of the first sheet:

[image]

And this is a screenshot of the second sheet. Note that cell A2 is a value:

[image]

And this is a screenshot of the second sheet. Note that cell A3 is a formula:

[image]

I'm importing the second sheet into R with this code:

```
library(readxl)
read_excel("~/Desktop/x.xlsx", col_names = TRUE, sheet = "sheet2")
```

Which gives this warning:

```
Warning message:
In read_fun(path = path, sheet = sheet, limits = limits, shim = shim,  :
  Expecting numeric in A3 / R3C1: got a date
```

`read_excel` is importing cell A3 as a date, but I need A3 to be imported as the value, which is 3. How can I import the value of cell A3?

Comment: try `col_types("numeric")` inside `read.excel("x.xlsx", col_types = c("numeric"), sheet= "Sheet2")`